# Recurrence for recursive insertion sort

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation, sorting

I tried this problem from CLRS (Page 39, 2.3-4)

> We can express insertion sort as a recursive procedure as follows. In order to sort `A[1... n]`, we recursively sort `A[1... n-1]` and then insert `A[n]` into the sorted array `A[1... n-1]`. Write a recurrence for the running time of this recursive version of insertion sort.

The recurrence I formed was

$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}\Theta(1) & \textrm{if } n = 1,\\
       T(n-1) + \Theta(n) & \textrm{if } n > 1.
\end{cases}
$$

**My reasoning**

- the base case of $n = 1$ the list is sorted so there is no work hence constant time.
- For all other cases the time depends on sorting the sequence `A[1...n-1]` and then insertion into that sequence. Hence it should be their sum, i.e., $T(n-1) + \Theta(n)$.

I wanted to know whether the recurrence relation is correct. If not what are the mistakes and how to correctly formulate a recurrence relation?

Comment: You may be interested in [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions). In particular, the notion of "runtime" is fuzzy, the recurrence with $\Theta$-terms is not the nicest way of putting things and several kinds of solving recurrences have been discussed. Note that "yes-no"-questions are generally undesired here. (I note that the question is old; leaving the comment for reference.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the description you provided the recurrence is correct.
you might think it should be

 T(n)=\begin{Bmatrix}
1 & ,\ n=1\\ 
T(n-1)\ +\ \Theta(log\ n) & ,\ otherwise 
\end{Bmatrix}

because you can find the insertion place by using Binary-Search, however in order to actually insert the element you'll have to move away all the elements in the worst case.

Comment: Searching linearly takes `O(n)` and by doing binary search it is `O(log n)`. But isn't the worst-case the movement of all the elements which should take `O(n)` hence making the overall complexity `O(n)`? So why is the term in `n != 1` is `O(log n)` instead of being `O(n)`?

Comment: you're right, that is exactly what i said. the above formula is wrong exactly because the movement of the elements takes O(n)

Comment: I should be reading more carefully. Thanks for answering.